# PHP foreach loop add numerical squence for results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to generate a numerical sequence for each result that is returned like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I have search all over and haven't found an answer so I'm hoping someone can help me here. Below is the code.

The output should look like

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" id="item_number_293" size="3" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required]"  value="293" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" id="item_name_293" style="width: 320px;" class="validate[required]" value="Fish"  />    
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_293" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" value="100" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" id="amount_293" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]"  value="$1,850.00"  />

<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" id="item_number_314" size="3" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required]"  value="314" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" id="item_name_314" style="width: 320px;" class="validate[required]" value="Dogs"  />    
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" id="quantity_314" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" id="amount_314" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]"  value="$1.00"  />

<input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" id="item_number_315" size="3" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required]"  value="315" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" id="item_name_315" style="width: 320px;" class="validate[required]" value="Cats"  />    
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" id="quantity_315" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" value="5" />
```

```
function generatePayPalCheckout($user_id) {
    include $_SESSION['db'];
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart 
            WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY cartid DESC";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        moduleError($e->getMessage());
        exit();
    }
    $results = $s->fetchAll();

    if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $username = userDeets($result['user_id']);
            $product =  getProductDeets($result['productid']);
            $getuseremail = $product['user_id'];
            $productowneremail = userDeets($getuseremail);

            $titlefix = str_replace(' ', '-', $product['title']);
            $titlefix = strtolower($titlefix);
            $titlefix = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-\s]+/i", "", $titlefix);
            $cartqty = $result['qty'];
            $productsubtotal = $result['qty'] * $product['price'];
            $qtydiff = $cartqty - $product['qty'];
            $qtyrequested = $result['qty'];
            $counter = 0 + 1;
            ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="item_number_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" size="3" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required]"  value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="item_name_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 320px;" class="validate[required]" value="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"  />    
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="quantity_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" value="<?php echo $result['qty']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="amount_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]"  value="<?php echo "$".number_format($productsubtotal, 2, '.', ','); ?>"  />
    <?php } } }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter will be always: 1

```
$counter = 0 + 1;
```

you can do something like:

```
if ($results) {
$i = 0;
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $username = userDeets($result['user_id']);
        $product =  getProductDeets($result['productid']);
        $getuseremail = $product['user_id'];
        $productowneremail = userDeets($getuseremail);

        $titlefix = str_replace(' ', '-', $product['title']);
        $titlefix = strtolower($titlefix);
        $titlefix = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-\s]+/i", "", $titlefix);
        $cartqty = $result['qty'];
        $productsubtotal = $result['qty'] * $product['price'];
        $qtydiff = $cartqty - $product['qty'];
        $qtyrequested = $result['qty'];

        $i++;           

        $counter = $i;
        ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="item_number_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" size="3" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required]"  value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="item_name_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 320px;" class="validate[required]" value="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"  />    
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="quantity_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" value="<?php echo $result['qty']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="amount_<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" style="width: 60px;" class="validate[required,custom[number]]"  value="<?php echo "$".number_format($productsubtotal, 2, '.', ','); ?>"  />
<?php } } }
```

use a variable *i* as a counter

Answer (score 0):

put your counter outside of your `foreach` loop

```
$counter = 0 + 1;
```

is going to return 1 everytime it loops..

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
```

then

```
$counter++;
```